# Store a formula in a table and use it for future calculations

Tags: database, postgresql

I need to store formulas into table (users must manage these formulas) and use it for calculate, using information of the database, some fields and store them. The formulas change over time and don't have constant variables.

The formula can be something like:

```
(a*b+c)/24.5
```

or

```
2456.789*a+b²-c+23.58*d
```

I am using PostgreSQL as database system. How can I implement this properly?

Answer (score 1):

If the formulae are valid SQL expressions, then you can run them with PL/PgSQL and `EXECUTE` ... but doing so is quite insecure, as the user can then invoke arbitrary SQL functions.

If they are not valid SQL expressions, then you must decide what they *will* be, and use an appropriate expression processor.

So before it's possible to really answer this usefully, you need to define what the formulae can and cannot do, what the level of trust for the users is, etc.

### Example: Using Python and SymPy

I just wanted pure expressions, I might use [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) with PL/Pythonu, though I don't like the lack of a sandboxed version. e.g.:

```
yum install sympy
```

(or your preferred `apt-get` equivalent) then

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eval_user_expr(userexpr text) 
RETURNS float8 
LANGUAGE plpythonu
AS $$
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
return float(parse_expr(userexpr));
$$;
```

or if you want to take variables as inputs too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eval_user_expr(userexpr text,  varnames text[], varvalues float8[]) 
RETURNS float8 
LANGUAGE plpythonu
AS $$
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
return float(parse_expr(userexpr, dict(zip(varnames, varvalues))));
```

then to use:

```
regress=# SELECT eval_user_expr('2456.789*a+b**2-c+23.58*d', ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ARRAY[3, 4, 9, 42]);
 eval_user_expr 
----------------
       8367.727
(1 row)
```

Of course, this is pretty clumsy. It's treating all values as double-precision floating point (Python's `float` is a double). I don't see a simple solution to that, as Python's hetrogenous-typed `dict` doesn't have a matching native PostgreSQL type. You could pass json or similar, but it's still quite limited.

This also requires that you use SymPy's expression syntax. So for example, `b²` isn't understood:

```
regress=# SELECT eval_user_expr('b²', ARRAY['b'], ARRAY[1]);
ERROR:  SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "eval_user_expr", line 3, in <module>
    return float(parse_expr(userexpr, dict(zip(varnames, varvalues))));
  PL/Python function "eval_user_expr", line 756, in parse_expr
  PL/Python function "eval_user_expr", line 690, in eval_expr
PL/Python function "eval_user_expr"
```

and you must use the Python form, `b**2`:

```
regress=# SELECT eval_user_expr('b**2', ARRAY['b'], ARRAY[1]);
 eval_user_expr 
----------------
              1
(1 row)
```

### Other options

PL/Lua, relying on its sandbox and running Lua expressions directly.

A custom C extension using an existing expression parsing and execution library (if you can find a good one). Maybe GNU `libmatheval` (I've never tried it or tested it).

PL/perl if you can find a suitable Perl expression parsing library. Or PL/V8 if you can find a JavaScript one. Or you're willing to run `pl/perl` sandboxed and run raw Perl expressions supplied by users.

PL/Java if you're desperate and can find something that meets your needs in Java.

Comment: What do you mean by PL/Java if your desperate? Is the PL/Java implementation bad or do you have a general distaste for Java personally?

Comment: @Bob PL/Java is one step away from unmaintained. It has big problems (e.g. it links java.util.logging to PostgreSQL's logging, but if you log in Java with `ERROR` level it'll cause an exception that aborts the whole PL/Java procedure. Exceedingly frustrating when using libraries. Finally, Java's heavyweight JVM process, lightweight threads model is a poor match to PostgreSQL's lightweight process model, so using PL/Java can often be frustrating in performance terms and in terms of the "Java Way" being different to what PostgreSQL wants you to do. Java's OK, my issues are with PL/Java.